# jQuery sequential XML filtering only working for first option chosen

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm writing a jQuery app to help users select a product from an online store. I'm doing this by sequentially filtering XML based on their choices. The problem with my code right now is that only the first option chosen (I'm only working with 2 options for now). If the user chooses "male" or "female" first, they see all the male or female wallets. But if they then select a material, the page does not change at all. The same is true of the opposite: if they select a material first, they see all the wallets of that material, but if they then select a gender, it does not narrow it down further.

Here is the applicable code:

```
$.get('wallets.xml', function(data) {
// Get the chosen wallets
if (genderChosen && genderChosen != "" && $walletsChosen instanceof jQuery) {
    $walletsChosen.filter('wallet[gender=' + genderChosen + ']');
}
else if (genderChosen && genderChosen != "") {
    $walletsChosen = $(data).find('wallet[gender=' + genderChosen + ']');
}
if (materialChosen && materialChosen != "" && $walletsChosen instanceof jQuery) {
    $walletsChosen.filter('wallet[material=' + materialChosen + ']');
    alert("material chosen, jQuery");
}
else if (materialChosen && materialChosen != "") {
    $walletsChosen = $(data).find('wallet[material=' + materialChosen + ']');
    alert("material chosen, non-jQuery");
}
// Print the chosen wallets
if ($walletsChosen instanceof jQuery) {
    $('#content').empty();
    $walletsChosen.each(function() {
        var $wallet = $(this);
        printWallet($wallet);
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Here is the URL: http://ajaxtest.walletwallets.com/ajax12.php (No errors in console)

Comment: Also, I tried putting alerts inside each "if" block to make sure they are being executed, and they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.filter` yields a filtered version of the source set. It does not alter the set itself.

Rather than just `$walletsChosen.filter(...)` you'd want to use `$wallesChosen = $wallestChosen.filter(...)`.

Comment: Thank you! That was a very noobish oversight on my part... (sorry)